# Bold text for python plot labels

Tags: python, plot

I want to use bold text for the labels of my python plot. I tried this:

```
plt.xlabel("$\mathrm{\\mathbf{\delta\\langle r^2\\rangle^{226,A}[fm^2]}}$",fontsize=50,fontweight='bold')
```

But the output looks weird (see the attached picture). The letters get bold, but the numbers and the symbols stay the same. How can I get everything in bold? Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using `weight` instead of `fontweight`.

**Update:**

I found that using `\boldsymbol` will work with the Greek letter.

```
\boldsymbol{\mathbf{text}}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. The output looks the same, even with weight.

Comment: @BillKet I 've just updated my answer, let me know if it works or not.